# Python thread Error: Thread is running with limited resource on GCE vm instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, python-multithreading

We have our code build in python which runs on Google Compute engine. The code processes data files from Cloud Storage to Bigquery. We are using 8 threads for multiprocessing. It has been tested successfully in some environments but in One environment, it keeps giving error:

```
{'status':'Service Running with limited resources-one or more worker threads have been terminated' deadthreads':7,'threadpoolsize':8,'alivethreads':1}
```

second and all other threads are dying after it .

Can anyone help with above error message ?

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you used?(do not include sensitive data). also please specify the environment that you have tested.

Comment: Thanks Milad for responding on this issue. Its resolved now and I am posting answer below as it might help someone who is getting similar issue on threadings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential reason for the issue was that the code was not comaptible with latest version of **google-auth** package . With vm spin up the default version installed **google-auth 1.4.1** however on other environments it was 
**google-auth 1.3.0**.
We downgraded this package to 1.3.0 and also downgraded **grpcio** package from 1.9.1 to 1.8.6 to bring environment in synch with tested environment.
Threading issue is resolved now.